# how to use ref property to change react-native element css style

Tags: react-native

I want to pass `ref` property to specify react-native element and change css style later,

however, I even couldn't get element from `this.refs.[name]` method, like below code.

```
<Text ref='foo' onPress={this._onPressText}>
  some text
</Text>
```

and callback method,

```
_onPressText: function() {
  console.log(this.refs.foo);  // log undefine here
}
```

what should I do?

thanks..

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't access the refs in that callback (did you check the 'this' binding?). But why (and how) do you want to change a components styling by referencing it directly? This is not how you usually would use react. I don't really understand your use case, but from what I gather in the _onPressText() function you should set some state value via setState(). In the render method you then use different styling depending on the state.

Comment: @dvinemultimedia  I understand your words, you means I could use `<Text style={{this.state.color, this.state.fontSize,}}>` etc to change css, am I right?

Comment: Yes. Even better you define two (or more) different styles in your Styles object and then you can just so something like  "let textStyle = (this.state.active) ? styles.activeStyle : styles.inactiveStyle" and then <Text style={ textStyle}>. This way the styles get cached and only the style ID is send of the bridge.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to manipulate the style of a component via its ref, you can achieve that like this:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
    this.textRef = React.createRef();
    this._onPressText = this._onPressText.bind(this);
  }

  _onPressText() {
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    console.log(this.textRef.current);
    
    //To change the css style of the component
    this.textRef.current.setNativeProps({
    style:{
    textDecorationLine: 'underline'
    }
    })
  }

  render() {
    // tell React that we want to associate the <text> ref
    // with the `textRef` that we created in the constructor
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      Text ref = 'foo'
      onPress = {
        this._onPressText
      } >
      some text <
      /Text> /
      div >
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there a way to get the nativeProps aswell? Like I want the current value of secureTextEntry